# Is it possible to click on text that is not a link using watir

Tags: watir, firewatir

i am using watir in the firefox browser

I am looking for a way to click on text that is not a link.  I have verified that the text exists on the website using

```
b.text.include? "Tasks"
```

I've tried several different ways to click on this text, but all have been unsuccessful, thus far i have tried

```
b.link(:text, "Tasks").click
b.text.click "Tasks"
b.text(:text, "Tasks").click
```

is there a way to click on this text using watir?  any help would be *greatly* appreciated

Comment: Would be really helpful to see where the text is in the DOM or the HTML :)

Answer (score 4):

If clicking on this text that is not a link causes something to happen, then it is likely that there is an *container element* that encapsulates the text which is 'wired' to execute some specific javascript when a particular event (like onMouseDown or onClick) is detected.  A large number of element types are possible (span, div, table cell, just to name a few) depending on how the developer designed the page.

Since multiple containers can be nested (ala a geek version of Russian Dolls) it's important to know or figure out which one will trigger the client side code when it is clicked.  To do this you need to look at the HTML for the page or use a developer tool (all modern browsers have them) to examine the DOM in the vicinity of the text that is 'clickable'

To give you a better answer that is anything but general advice, **We Need To See The HTML** for that part of the page in order to be able to tell what kind of element this is, and suggest the proper *(how, what)* values and element type that would be needed in order to create the line of code that would click on the element, or fire the needed event.

Until you can provide that additional detail (EDIT your question to add the information to it) your question and hence the answers as well, will all suffer from [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_In,_Garbage_Out) syndrome

Comment: +1. This. It's important to know how to approach this kind of issue, as it comes up many times in different places.

Answer (score 2):

If the text you're trying to click is contained in a paragraph or span tag, could possibly select it this way? You could also use the :id selector if the wrapping tag had an identifier. Hopefully that works.

I don't know your use-case, but if the text *could* be a link, you could use [event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) on the click event to keep it from doing anything.

Comment: I've used both span, div or class tags to click on text elements.

Comment: thank you both! it appears that i only have the id's, but how would i use the id to click on the element?  i used `b.link(:id, "left_nav_tasks").click` but to no avail.  is there any other information that would be important for me to provide to help aid in answering this question?

Comment: Well, I'm not finding another example of none-link clicking. Could you tell us more about why exactly you need to test this?

Comment: @drew, what element type is the ID value associated with?  show us the html